# What is the meaning of this expression "in measure to"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of this expression "in measure to" in such a sentence as:

> "These acts of censorship were done *in measure to government regulations*."

Comment: Where is this from?

Comment: I'd either have to guess or ask the writer. It's not English as I know it.

Comment: It might mean something like "These acts of censorship were done in accordance with a measure (or measures) taken from government regulations", with the word measure meaning "a step planned or taken as a means to an end". But as it stands, I agree it's not standard English.

Comment: A Google search does not produce a match for the example sentence at any site other than EL&U, which leads me to suspect that the sentence is a creation of the question poster. I recommend closing the question unless and until the poster can provide a real-world example of "in measure to" used in a way that the poster doesn't understand.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if the writer means “*in accordance with ...*”, “*according to ...*”, “*consistent with ...*”, “*in parallel with ...*”, or even “*in proportionate accord with ...*”. All these alternatives contain some measure of “*measure*”, as one might say.